# how do I use the Google Line Chart gadget to access data in Google App Engine Datastore

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, google-gadget

- I have some data in a Google App Engine (GAE) Datastore.
- I have a google site and have inserted a Google Line Chart (GLC) gadget.
- I want to chart that data with the GLC gadget.

Can I use the standard GLC to do this, and if so how?

or do I have to customize my own GLC (copy and modify)?  If so, I presume I have to modify the javascript, yes?

Could someone post a samll example of how to access the GAE Datastore with Java Script.

Comment: Is the site that is presenting the GLC gadget powered by GAE?  Or is it another site and you will be using an AJAX call to get the data from GAE?  Makes a big difference.

Comment: It is the official GLC from Google, so I presume it is powered by GAE.  I don't believe there is any AJAX involved (but that's just a guess).

Comment: My data isn't in Google Datastore (yet) -- I just thought that was the natural fit, but maybe using one of the other APIs to store as a Google Spreadsheet or file on Google Drive might work better?  I've been going around in circles reading all the Google API docs (with some tutorials often referring to deprecated APIs)... sigh.  Maybe the GAE can dish out the gadget directly rather than using Google Sites?  but I wanted something quick and easy, with the ability to have different user profiles.

Comment: GLC and GAE don't really have anything to do with with other. You probably don't want to use GAE.

Comment: A bit more background.  Data will be coming from many sensors in different geographical locations.  I thought I would http post the data every hour (possibly more frequently) and GAE seemed like a good option to grab the data from the post and store it somewhere (GDS?) for later retrieval and display (Sites? and/or Gadgets?)